# Which test do I use for comparing site differences with unequal sample sizes?

Tags: anova, excel

I have fish gene expression data from various contaminated and reference sites. We measured the expression of 4 thyroid hormones in each fish at 5 sites. Site 1 had the fewest fish of only 6. The site with the most fish has data for 20 fish.

I'm wondering how to compare the 4 hormones across 5 sites that have unequal sample sizes. Is an ANOVA appropriate? I am working in Excel currently.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options (1) compare each hormone separately, (2) do a repeated measures analysis on all four simultaneously. I assume that the levels of the hormones are correlated in some way so option 2 has some advantages in taking that correlation into account. Either way some form of ANOVA would work. Option 2 is sometimes called MANOVA. I think you would be better to use a proper statistical package for these analyses especially the repeated measures one.